# showing multiple point with description in map

Tags: android, ios, html, google-maps, cordova

I am working on a cross platform app both for android and iOS. I am using `phonegap` as bridge between HTML5 and android/iOS.

In my database there is multiple geo point(`latitude`& `longitude`). It is easy to show a point in the map by below

```
//Javascript//collecting data from database with JSON

var map = new GoogleMap();
map.initialize("map_home_location",data[0].home_lat,data[0].home_lng);

////HTML5

<div class="rhtForm" style="height:250px;" id="map_home_location"></div>
```

One geo location point is showing properly.

But i want to show

```
1) multiple geo location point in a map with short description of each point. 
2) When click into a point long description will show.
```

here description means other information stored with specific geo location point.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Marker newMark = 
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
.position(lat,lng)
.title("title")
.snippet("short desc"));

Then you have the marker you just added in an object to modify if you want. Otherwise you cab just use add marker. The title and snippet pop up on clicking the marker by default.